# Word that means the barrier or transition between life and death

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can accurately describe the transition or barrier into death from life and into life from death (this is for a video game, so verbs like to spawn and respawn seem appropriate). I don't really want a verb like "transition" or "passing" because both are a little too general.

An example sentence could be:
"Let's animate the ___"

The word doesn't need to be a noun, and a short phrase may work as well.

Comment: Perhaps *life* and *death* themselves are not appropriate words here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Christianity, which is the religion that has most influenced English such that such terms tend to come from Christianity, the term most often used for this is "veil."

Here are some examples:

https://www.catholicstand.com/living-thin-veil-earth-heaven/

https://steemit.com/life/@spiritualmatters/the-veil-between-life-and-death-is-very-thin

https://foreverconscious.com/death-rituals-and-the-thinning-veil

http://www.metamedianews.com/2018/01/the-veil-between-life-death/